# Trying to update two tables in single action method and got error: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I am trying to insert data to Order and OrderItem tables from a action method 'Checkout' as shown in code below. But I am getting an error 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker'. How to add data to both tables Order and OrderItem?? The codes are as shown below:

```
public ActionResult Checkout([Bind(Include = "UserId,Address1,Address2,OrderDateTime,Town,Country,PostalCode,TotalPrice")] Order order)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<OrderItem> orderItems = new List<OrderItem>();

            db.Orders.Add(order);
            db.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var product in ((CartViewModel)Session["Cart"]).SelectedProducts)
            {
                orderItems.Add(new OrderItem { Order = order, Product = product });
            }


            db.OrderItems.AddRange(orderItems);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Model classes are:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderItemID { get; set; }
    public virtual int OrderID{ get; set; }
    public virtual int ProductID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderID")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public virtual string UserID { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }

    public bool OrderShipped { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? OrderDateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Town { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Can you remove foreign key reference in both table? If possible than you will manage with it.

Comment: I think the error says that you have created multiple instances of your database context. For simple applications, I always use `using(MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext())` in all methods whithin which I enclose all transactions. Once the program leaves the `using()` scope, the object `db` is automatically disposed.

Comment: @Vishal Kiri, removing foreign key reference did not work for me.

Comment: @Celdor, I tried it your way too but I got the same error at same line of code.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the same thing but in a different way?

Comment: I think this line is the problem: `orderItems.Add(new OrderItem { Order = order, Product = product });` because your tables are related via OrderID, yet you are trying to add an object to `OrderItem`. What you need to do is add orders, save it, read their IDs from the database and then add those IDs.

Comment: ONe more thing, you have navigation properties in `OrderItem`: `public virtual Order Order { get; set; }`. Shouldn't you have navigation property in table `Order`, e.g. `ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }`? If you want to map tables 1 to many, it should be done this way. I think you probably have multiple instances of your data context and you have already done something with `Order` or `OderItem` or both and these objects are locked and this is why you have this error. It is hard to conclude anything because your code is not complete.

Comment: This is excellent tutorial on Navigation is [here](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first). The EF tutorials can be found [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you pass multiple instance of Product.
Try to change

```
[ForeignKey("ProductID")]
public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
```

to

```
[ForeignKey("Product")]
public int Product_Id { get; set; } 

public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
```

Comment: It did not work as well. Still same error at same line of code.     db.OrderItems.AddRange(orderItems);    this is the code where i get the error    'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.'

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the same thing but in a different way?

Comment: Modify **Product** and **Order**.then try to debug. Add a breakpoint to line1(if statement)
i think your declaration is similar to `protected db yourDbContext = new yourDbContext();`

Comment: I am still getting the same error. What did I do wrong?

Comment: If the solution in this answer did not work, why the answer is mark as the best answer?